# VBA excel, finding corresponding values in columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have managed to loop through two columns to find if the value in one column is present in the other column.

Now the next step is to determine if values present in both columns contain the same value in the cell on the right-hand side of the value.

The picture of the desired result and the current result should explain what I want to achieve.

P.S. dont be confused by the code, as the columns in my workbook are on two different sheets.

[image]

I have tried looping twice through the columns once I get the confirmation of a match, but at this point, Im just lost.... sorry

```
Sub loopDb()

    Set dbsheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dbsheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lr1 = dbsheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = dbsheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lr1
        act1 = dbsheet1.Cells(x, 1)

        For y = 2 To lr2
            act2 = dbsheet2.Cells(y, 1)

            If Not dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "Match" Then
                'Only compare if previoulsy not done or resulted in "No match"
                If act2 = act1 Then
                    dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "Match"

                    If dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "Match" Then
                        For i = 2 To lr1
                            If dbsheet2.Cells(y, 1).Value = dbsheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                                dbsheet2.Cells(y, 4).Value = "Match"
                            Else
                                dbsheet2.Cells(y, 4).Value = "No match"
                            End If
                        Next i
                    End If

                 Else
                 dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "No match"
                End If
            End If
        Next y

    Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use `application.worksheetfunction.match(col1value,col2,0)` and `AND` in your logic, so `if match1 AND match2 then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nathan_Sav pointed out, you can solve your issue with the match formula.

This [`MATCH` formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) lets you work completely without vba.

Formula for matching col1 and col2:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(sheet1!A1;sheet2!$A$1:$A$10;0)>=0;"Match");"No match")
```

The Match formula returns the index where the match was found. An error otherwise. To get the words "Match" and "No match" we need the `IF` and `IFERROR` formula.

Formula for matching of both col1 & val1 and col2 & val 2

```
{=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(sheet1!A1&sheet1!B1;sheet2!$A$1:$A$10&sheet2!$B$1:$B$10;0)>=0;"Match");"No match")}
```

Combining the two columns of sheet2 makes the use of an array formula necessary. In order to make it work, hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

I hope this helps